# Netsuite saved search - PO fulfilling transaction date

Tags: formula, netsuite

I'm trying to create a formula in NetSuite, so the that my saved search shows all POs with a fulfilling transaction date of older than 90 days, but not empty. I can get both of these formulas to work on their own, but not on the same report. The formula I'm using is

CASE WHEN {fulfillingtransaction.trandate} IS NOT NULL AND (SYSDATE - {fulfillingtransaction.trandate}) > 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0

Then I'm putting formula equal to value 1

I know the report should return a few hundred transactions, but I keep getting zero results. Can anyone help?

Multiple attempts.  I can get both of these formulas to work on their own, but not on the same report.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be any difference between your formula and just doing a relative search on the fulfilling transaction date:

[image: Search on Receipt Date]

One thing though is that search doesn't work on the main line so if you have `Mainline == true` then you'll get no results.